# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'max'

Tags: python-3.x

I did the above code, I got the error message "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'max'." How should I do?

Python 3.7.2, numpy-1.17.2, macOS 10.14.5, and jupyter notebook

```
import numpy as np
np.array(range(10))
```

or

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(1, 51)
```

Comment: Is the file you're running this from called `numpy.py` by any chance?

Comment: Oh, sorry, how can I check about your question?

Comment: If there is a file in the same directory as your code with the name `numpy.py` (even if it's the same file), `import numpy` statements will only import that file. Check the value of `np.__file__` to see what file is being imported.

Comment: Thank you for your comment for all, but I have no files with the name including "numpy" or "init." 
The file is being imported is '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'